# CropBox unique number as order reference PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using CropBox to upload a cropped image for use in an order for printing.
I need a unique number which is being generated by a .txt file but I can't get the file to be save with the same order number. The number keeps increasing no matter what I try to do to only increase the order number when it doesn't already exist. The script uses javascript that I am not used to and I can't seem to make it do what I need.

````
<?php

    session_start();    


$imgW = 200;
$imgH = 300;


if(isset($_SESSION['OrNo'])){
    $counter = $_SESSION['OrNo'];

    echo $counter;
}else{

$counter = file_get_contents(strtolower("orderno.txt")) + 1;
file_put_contents("orderno.txt", $counter);
$_SESSION['OrNo'] = $counter;

}
 $filename =  'custupload/'.$counter. '.png';



if(isset($_REQUEST['doAction']) && $_REQUEST['doAction']== 'submit'){
    
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

        $output_file = $filename;
        //$Globals ['outputfile'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $output_file);
        $ret['status'] = true;
        $ret['msg'] = "Your file has been added to the product! $output_file";
        echo json_encode($ret);
        
        exit;
        
               
    }
}
?>

<center>
<?php 
  $Productid = $_REQUEST["Productid"]; 
  $ImgTemplate = $_REQUEST["ImgTemplate"]; 
  $pic = $_REQUEST["ImgTemplate"]; 
?>


<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.cropbox.css">
<form id="formbanner" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="banner" class="upImage" >
    <input type="hidden" name="photo" value="" id="fileinp">
    <br>
    <br>
    <img class="cropimage" id="myImg" src="#" alt="" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="save_banner" value="Submit">
                        <img class="loadingimage" style="display: none;" src="loading.gif" width="64" height="20"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    
</form>
</div>

<?php echo "$Productid";?>&ImgTemplate=<?php echo "$ImgTemplate";?>&filename=<?php echo "$filename";?>

 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
var myImage = '';   
$(function () {
   
    $(".upImage").change(function () {
       
        var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
           alert('Please select a valid image [ jpg | jpeg | gif | png ]');
            $(this).val('');
            myImage= '';
            clearImage();
       
        }else{   
       
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        }
    });
    
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('.cropCont').show();
        $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#myImg').show();
        $( '.cropimage' ).cropbox( {width: <?php echo $imgW; ?>, height: <?php echo $imgH; ?>, showControls: 'auto' } ).on('cropbox', function( event, results, img ) {
            myImage = img.getDataURL();
        });
    }
    
    function clearImage(){
        $('.cropCont').hide();
        $("#banner").val('');
        $("#myImg").removeAttr('src');
        $('#myImg').hide();
    }
    
    $('#formbanner').submit(function(e){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#save_banner').attr('disabled',true);
        $('.loadingimage').show();
        var form = $('#formbanner')[0]; 
        var fd = new FormData(form);
        if(myImage != ''){
            var block = myImage.split(";");
            var contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];// In this case "image/gif"
            var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];// In this case "R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM...."
            var blob = b64toBlob(realData, contentType);
            fd.append("image", blob);
        }
        $.ajax({
          url: '?doAction=submit',
          data: fd,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType : 'json',
          success: function(data){
             alert(data.msg);
             if(data.status){
                window.location='test.php?Productid=<?php echo "$Productid";?>&ImgTemplate=<?php echo "$ImgTemplate";?>&ONo=<?php echo "$counter";?>';
            }else{
                $('#save_banner').attr('disabled',false);
                $('.loadingimage').hide(3000);
            }


          }
        });

    });
});






function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

      var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
      return blob;
}


    </script>
             ```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful. 
I have tried using session variables as well as creating the variable within the page.
````

Comment: Is there a `session_start` somewhere before this (in a file that includes this one, or something)? If not, then `isset($_SESSION['OrNo'])` will never be true …

Comment: (This doesn’t sound like a very good approach to begin with, with multiple users using this at the same time, you are likely to run into problems with this at some point …)

Comment: Yes, there's an include file for database connections etc. I removed the link to try and simplify the code

Comment: @CBroe happy to take any suggestions on a better way to do this, always looking to try and improve :D

Comment: Well first of all, if you are using a database in the project already, then you should rather use that to store such counters as well, rather than plain text files. The database at least has all the mechanisms necessary to deal with concurrent access already built-in, whereas with text files that’s always a bit of a gamble.

Comment: Second, I don’t see why you are trying to determine this counter value on every page load already - you only need it, when you actually process an uploaded image, right? So the value could be determined right there in that particular if branch only to begin with. And if you need to use the determined value further along in the whole process, then you could put it into the user session then, at that point.

Comment: @CBroe I've avoided doing much with the Javascript so that I don't muck anything up! Thanks for the tips, I'll have a go and see what happens (or doesn't!)